# Insertion of blank pages in Thesis using document class Thesis

Tags: chapters, templates, blank-page

I am writing my thesis and want to insert blank pages after Declaration, Abstract, Acknowledgments, etc. and also after each chapter so that the next chapter/ section starts from odd-numbered page. I am using Thesis document class. Is there any one to help me? Thanks.

Comment: This is the kind of case where a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) can make all the difference between an answer which would work for you only in a different possible world and one which will work for you in the actual world. I do not know which `Thesis.cls` you are referring to - it does not seem to be in TeX Live. So a link to the class, alongside your MWE would be extremely useful.

Comment: This is the link of Thesis.cls  http://kentlab3.physics.nyu.edu/thesis/downloads/thesis_1/Thesis.cls

Answer (score 1):

`Thesis.cls` uses `vmargin` to configure the page dimensions so you should use this interface if you wish to alter those dimensions. Otherwise, you are likely to get inconsistent and undesired results.

The command used by `Thesis` is:

```
\setmarginsrb {1.5in} % left margin
              {0.6in} % top margin
              {1in} % right margin
              {0.8in} % bottom margin
              {20pt} % head height
              {0.25in} % head sep
              {9pt} % foot height
              {0.3in} % foot sep
```

which obviously sets a wider left (inner) margin than right (outer) margin:

[image: default margins]

The idea here is that once an allowance has been made for binding, the amount of white space in the middle of a double-page spread should be equal to that at each outer edge.

That may be good typography but it has no place in the formatting guidelines of your institution. (Good typography is alien to most such guidelines.)

If you want inner and outer margins of 36mm, try this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb {36mm} % left margin
              {0.6in} % top margin
              {36mm} % right margin
              {0.8in} % bottom margin
              {20pt} % head height
              {0.25in} % head sep
              {9pt} % foot height
              {0.3in} % foot sep
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
    \kant[1-15]
\end{document}
```

[image: adjusted margins]

Comment: It's very unfortunate that templates use the `vmargin` package: it abuses `\voffset` and `\hoffset`, making it incompatible with several packages (notably `atbegshi`).

Comment: @egreg What would you suggest? The class is loading it regardless. (I just used `book` here because I don't have the class.) The other option would be to edit the class, removing all the `vmargin` stuff and then use `geometry` or whatever to manage the page. But I wasn't sure if the OP wanted to edit the class or what side-effects that might have. The documentation suggested you could stop it messing with the offset values but, again, I think that would mean modifying the class (and it would be simpler in that case to just remove the package I suspect).

Comment: The only remedy is to change the template.

Comment: @egreg Yes. That would probably be best.

Answer (score 0):

Add `openright` to your documentclass options.

Manually you can do it with `\cleardoublepage`

Comment: I have tried openright but it didn't worked.

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside, openright]{Thesis} This is what I am using to include documentclass

Comment: Onesided documents have no right nor left pages. If you print two-sided, take a two sided layout, if not there is no point of starting a chapter on odd pages.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. Now its working perfectly after replacing oneside with twoside!

Comment: But this has changed the alignment of text in pages. Now even pages are appearing towards left side and odd pages are towards right side. I need single alignment throughout the document.

Comment: If you are printing double sided you should have margins like this: 2:1 1:2 so that the total margin in the middle is the margin on the right and left side. You should read the first chapter of this on typesetting: http://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf (fundamentals on page layout)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use the two-sided layout option as suggested by @MaxNoe

The default margin is what is done in professional typography.

However some institutions still have rules which break these conventions, such as fixed margins on all pages.

You have two options, adjust the document's margins while using `twoside`, or go back to your original document and force a blank page with something like: `\clearpage ~ \clearpage`. The non-breaking space means that the page won't be treated as empty and therefore discarded.

Answer (score 0):

So the best solution is to perform following steps:

1) Use twoside and openright options within \documentclass to insert blank pages as shown below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside, openright]{Thesis}
```

2) Use \setlength command in preamble after package definitions to get unified or fixed page margins throughout the document, as shown below.

```
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{36mm} 
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{36mm}
```

Note that \setlength should be inserted before \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix} package, otherwise the table of content may not appear in the output file!

Comment: Are you sue that `Thesis` does not use any package to manage the page layout e.g. `geometry`, `typearea` etc.? Because if it does, setting the margins manually will confuse the calculations. (And if it does not, you would almost certainly be better off using such a package.)

Comment: What do you mean by "setting the margins manually will confuse the calculations". Could you please explain it? Also, Could you please give an example for unified margins using geometry, typearea etc. Thanks!

Comment: If the class uses one of those packages (or similar) to set up the page, then it is important that the package know about any changes to the dimensions since it relies on that information to calculate things like text width and height, the width of margin paragraphs and their separation etc. etc. (Similarly for vertical dimensions.) If you change them manually, you are likely to end up with inconsistent layout, possibly even impossible layout (e.g. part of the logical page might not fit on the paper), and so on. So if the class uses such a package, you should only use that package's interface.

Comment: There are a lot of packages you can use to manage page layout. If you just want to browse them, try searching ctan or this site. If you say which package you need to use, I can give an example for that package but I don't see much point in giving a whole bunch for a whole bunch of different packages. The interfaces differ quite a bit. What you want is easy with `geometry`, for example, but you need a hack to do it with `typearea` because the Koma packages try to enforce good typographical choices (and the thesis rules are enforcing bad ones :(.)

Comment: It is using [vmargin](http://ctan.org/pkg/vmargin) so you should use its interface to alter the margins. Also, you should definitely do this in the preamble. The command in the class is `\setmarginsrb  { 1.5in}  % left margin
                        { 0.6in}  % top margin
                        { 1.0in}  % right margin
                        { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep`. So you could use that with your values.

Comment: Do you mean I should replace \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{36mm} 
                           \setlength{\evensidemargin}{36mm}     with above (your suggested) values in preamble and also keep above values in Thesis.cls file or I should remove above values from Thesis.cls file? Also, how would it effect both odd and even-numbered pages?

Comment: Please explicitly mention that what changes in which file I need to make, as I am still a novice user of Latex. Thanks.

Comment: Don't change the file. Just replace the manual settings in your preamble with the above, modifying the values appropriately. (So likely the `1.5in` and `1in` should be `36mm`.)

Comment: See egreg's comments on my answer. You might want to just modify the class file.